# Android: how would I create this resource shape in code?

Tags: android

I have this shape defined in an xml file, and need to create it in code but am stumped.

I assume I want to instantiate a RoundRectShape and set its properties to those in xml, but properties don't line up very well.

```
RoundRectShape(float[] outerRadii, RectF inset, float[] innerRadii)
```

My xml shape only has 1 radius, now RectF, and the RoundRectShape has no options for setting padding or colors?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> 
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
    <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom drawable siomething like the following

**Sample Code**

```
public class CustomDrawable extends ShapeDrawable{
    Paint fillpaint, strokepaint;
    private static final int WIDTH = 2; 

@Override
protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  super.onDraw(shape, canvas, paint);
    fillpaint = this.getPaint();
    strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
    strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    //to set stroke width and color instead of <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> 
    strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(WIDTH);
    strokepaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

    shape.draw(canvas, fillpaint);
    shape.draw(canvas, strokepaint);

}
}
```